# number weekdays starting on the first monday of the month

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to number weekdays for every month starting on the first monday of the month.

found this on SO, how do i number the weekdays in any month?

so, lets say, in October 2023, first Monday is 10/2/2023.

so, the numbering starts on the 1st Monday of the month and goes until the next month's first Monday. The numbering would go until 11/3/2023, and then would restart 11/6/2023

The weekends aren't counted, so, if Friday is a 5, next Monday is a 6

```
Public Function FirstMonday(myDate As Date) As Date

    Dim d As Date, w As Long
    d = DateSerial(Year(myDate), month(myDate), 1)
    w = Weekday(d, vbMonday)
    FirstMonday = d + IIf(w <> 1, 8 - w, 0)

End Function
```

Comment: If a month begins on a Tuesday, what number(s) would the Tuesday-Friday get?

Comment: hey, they would belong to the previous month. so, the week starts on the first monday of the month and goes until the next month's first monday, will fix the original post, thank you

Comment: What is the expected output for a weekend?

Comment: null, theyre skipped, the numbering jumps to the next work day. so, if Friday was 5, saturday and sunday are skipped and next Monday is 6

Comment: Where do you want to do this numbering? Do you want a function that takes in a date value and returns a day number? Oct 18 2023 would be day 13 of Oct? Nov 1 2023 would be day 23 of Oct?

Comment: sorry, just saw, yes, functoun would return the day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming dates are U.S. standard of MM/DD/YYYY, consider:

```
Function GetDayNum(myDate As Date) As Variant
Dim dteStart As Date, dteEnd As Date, intD As Integer
If Weekday(myDate, vbSaturday) < 3 Then
    GetDayNum = Null
Else
    intD = 1
    dteStart = FirstMonday(myDate)
    dteEnd = FirstMonday(DateSerial(Year(myDate), Month(myDate) + 1, 1))
    If myDate < dteStart Then dteStart = FirstMonday(DateSerial(Year(myDate), Month(myDate) - 1, 1))
    Do Until dteStart = dteEnd
        If dteStart = myDate Then
            GetDayNum = intD
            Exit Do
        Else
            If Weekday(dteStart, vbSaturday) > 2 Then intD = intD + 1
            dteStart = dteStart + 1
        End If
    Loop
End If
End Function
```

Non-U.S. structure dates might require different handling. If encounter issue, perhaps format each date like: `Format$(varDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy#")`. More info at http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Also, possibly need to include month/year in output so that day numbers from crossover week are attached to the correct month/year group. That should be a simple adjustment to extract month and year from dteStart to a variable at beginning of procedure then attach it to intD in the loop. This could not be a date value, it would have to be a string, something like: `03:10:2023`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assemble a couple of my functions for this:

```vb
Public Function WorkDayMonthWeek( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date) _
    As Variant
  
    Dim DateFirst       As Date
    Dim DayNumber       As Variant
    
    If Weekday(Date1, vbMonday) > 5 Then
        DayNumber = Null
    Else
        DateFirst = DateWeekdayInMonthFirst(Date1, vbMonday)
        If DateFirst > Date1 Then
            ' Date1 belongs to the previous month.
            DateFirst = DateWeekdayInMonthFirst(DateAdd("m", -1, Date1), vbMonday)
        End If
        DayNumber = 1 + DateDiffWorkdays(DateFirst, Date1)
    End If
  
    WorkDayMonthWeek = DayNumber
  
End Function
```

It will also take count of holidays, if you wish.

Full code at my repository at **GitHub**: [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).

| No. | Date1 | WorkDayNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-09-25 | 16 |
| 1 | 2023-09-26 | 17 |
| 2 | 2023-09-27 | 18 |
| 3 | 2023-09-28 | 19 |
| 4 | 2023-09-29 | 20 |
| 5 | 2023-09-30 | Null |
| 6 | 2023-10-01 | Null |
| 7 | 2023-10-02 | 1 |
| 8 | 2023-10-03 | 2 |
| 9 | 2023-10-04 | 3 |
| 10 | 2023-10-05 | 4 |
| 11 | 2023-10-06 | 5 |
| 12 | 2023-10-07 | Null |
| 13 | 2023-10-08 | Null |
| 14 | 2023-10-09 | 6 |
| 15 | 2023-10-10 | 7 |
| 16 | 2023-10-11 | 8 |
| 17 | 2023-10-12 | 9 |
| 18 | 2023-10-13 | 10 |
| 19 | 2023-10-14 | Null |
| 20 | 2023-10-15 | Null |
| 21 | 2023-10-16 | 11 |
| 22 | 2023-10-17 | 12 |
| 23 | 2023-10-18 | 13 |
| 24 | 2023-10-19 | 14 |
| 25 | 2023-10-20 | 15 |
| 26 | 2023-10-21 | Null |
| 27 | 2023-10-22 | Null |
| 28 | 2023-10-23 | 16 |
| 29 | 2023-10-24 | 17 |
| 30 | 2023-10-25 | 18 |
| 31 | 2023-10-26 | 19 |
| 32 | 2023-10-27 | 20 |
| 33 | 2023-10-28 | Null |
| 34 | 2023-10-29 | Null |
| 35 | 2023-10-30 | 21 |
| 36 | 2023-10-31 | 22 |
| 37 | 2023-11-01 | 23 |
| 38 | 2023-11-02 | 24 |
| 39 | 2023-11-03 | 25 |
| 40 | 2023-11-04 | Null |
| 41 | 2023-11-05 | Null |
| 42 | 2023-11-06 | 1 |
| 43 | 2023-11-07 | 2 |
| 44 | 2023-11-08 | 3 |
| 45 | 2023-11-09 | 4 |

Comment: hey, thank you very much, couldn't find this function though DateWeekdayInMonthFirst.

Comment: It is in module [DateFind](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date/blob/master/DateFind.bas).